# I want to remove the flickering effect above the image on hover

Tags: html, css

I have to display a list of products and on hover show some additional information. But on hover, it is flickering a lot. I am not able to understand how to remove that. Any help will be appreciated to remove flickering a lot on hover.

```css
.fixed-width-200 {
    width: 200px;
}

.img-responsiveExtended {
    display: block;
    height: 550px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: central;
    padding-top: 20px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.parentContent {
    position: relative;
    /*border:outset;
    border-width:thin;
    margin:0px;*/
}

.contentWithMargin {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:150px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    opacity:0.8;
 }

.imageContentStyle {
    z-index: 0;
    float:left;
}

.columnBorder {
    border: outset;
}

.divWithCenterImgStyle {
    text-align:center;
}

.dealPriceStyle {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 parentContent" id="parentDiv">
          <div class="imageContentStyle">
            <div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="divWithCenterImgStyle">
                  <center>
                    <img class=
                         "img-responsiveExtended img-container" src=
                         "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/A15JTuUMDOL._UY679_.jpg">
                  </center>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <div style="text-align:right">
                    <strike>
                    </strike> 
                    <span class=
                          "dealPriceStyle">
                      <mark>
                        <label>$
                        </label>58.00
                      </mark>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5>Calvin Klein Women&#39;s Two-Color Fringe Scarf
                <small>
                  <a href=
                     "/DreamsNDeals/Home/DealsByVendor?vendorId=1">Amazon
                  </a>
                </small>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="contentWithMargin collapse" id="38">
            <div>
              <div class="row modal-body">
                <h6>
                  <span class="label label-warning">
                    <span class=
                          "glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </h6>
                <h5>
                  <small>
                  </small>
                </h5>
                <!-- this text is coming as a flickering effect -->
                <p class="text-primary">100% Acrylic Imported
                  Machine Wash 16&quot; wide Color-blocked scarf with
                  fringe trim Made in China
                </p>
                <p class="text-info">Free Shipping
                </p>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href=
                       "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00Z69JVR8/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=9325&amp;creativeASIN=B00Z69JVR8&amp;linkCode=as2&amp;tag=dreamsndeal02-20&amp;linkId=CAQNU4JFUUNNWPUB"
                       target="_blank">Get Deal &raquo;
                    </a>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <p class="text-primary">
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see the main HTML code and the CSS code as above.

Comment: To get answers, you should add a working code sample. Your current sample doesn't show your css at all.

Comment: @Schlaus - How can edit the question now and add css to it . I am new to stackoverflow. i dont know how to edit a question after posting or is it possible to edit or not

Comment: The edit link isn't exactly hard to find, considering you were able to find the "add a comment" link.

Comment: Gah! The `<center>` element??

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanxx .. I have edited

Comment: Bootstrap + `center`, dude, I hope you're not demanding on code quality.

Comment: Anyway, when it comes to flickering effects, you should provide a live demo and tell what is your configuration (os, browser, version), so we can help.